# JPA: using @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true") does not set a boolean to TRUE in H2 database

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I defined one of the entity attributes to have a default boolean value set to true:

```java
    @NotNull
    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private Boolean free = true;
...
```

But it does not seem to work properly when I create this entity in a test:

```java
@DataJpaTest
class DeviceRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private DeviceRepository repository;

@Test
    public void testFindByFirstFreeTrue() {
        Device device = buildDevice("D-1");

        entityManager.persist(device);
        entityManager.flush();

        Device freeDevice = repository.findFirstByFreeTrue();
        assertThat(freeDevice).isNotNull();
        assertThat(freeDevice.getDeviceId()).isEqualTo("D-1");
        assertThat(freeDevice.getFree()).isTrue();
    }
```

it fails on the very first assertion. When I checked in debug mode the created entity, the attribute `free` was `null`. What am I missing?